# Redirect all Angular URLs with hash to Routes without hash

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I've changed my angular app from using hash (#) to non-hash and everything works perfectly.

Some of my users have bookmarked the site with the hash, and therefore I would like to redirect all hash routes to a non-hash route.

I can do it in the code, but I prefer to do it before, because of SEO considerations. Maybe at the level of Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor (private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (!!event.url && event.url.match(/^\/#/)) {
            this.router.navigate([event.url.replace('/#', '')]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Let me know in case of any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor (private router: Router) { 
     this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (!!event.url && event.url.match(/^\/#/)) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(event.url.replace('/#', ''));
          }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to explain what your code does and who your solution is a good way of solving the problem.